# Convert Date & Time with SimpleDateFormat from one TimeZone to another TimeZone

Tags: java, android

I have a string with a "bad" formatted date & time which I need to convert to a `Date` object so I can format it's contents using the `SimpleDateFormat` and the current `Locale`.

However, no matter how I try, I can never get the ouput to show the correct time, I convert from a PST time (UTC-8) to GMT, but the printed hour is +1 hour too much, GMT is only +7 from the (currently PDT) timezone.

I've tried the code on two Android devices, one set to GMT and one set to CET, one Android emulator, and running from command-line, all of them get the hour wrong. (+1)

**What am I doing wrong in my code below?**

```
    String sourceSDFformatter = "MMM d, h:mm a Z";
    String destSDFformatter = "EEEEE, MMMMM dd, HH:mm";
    String dateString = "Mar 20th, 10:00 AM PST".replaceAll("st|nd|rd|th", "");

    SimpleDateFormat sourceSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(sourceSDFformatter, Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat destSDF = new SimpleDateFormat(destSDFformatter, Locale.UK);

    TimeZone sourceTZ = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    TimeZone destTZ = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");

    sourceSDF.setTimeZone(sourceTZ);
    destSDF.setTimeZone(destTZ);

    Date myDate = sourceSDF.parse(dateString);
    myDate.setYear(new Date().getYear());

    System.out.println("Your Time: " + destSDF.format(myDate));
```

Outputs:

`Your Time: Wednesday, March 20, 18:00`

When my **expected** output would be: `Your Time: Wednesday, March 20, 17:00`.

I've tried the SO answer in [Conversion of local time zone to GMT in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414904) and it works perfectly if I change `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")`, then the printed hour is +7 hours ahead which is correct.

Comment: The answer to any java Date problem is JodaTime: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Your example produced the `expected` output.  BTW, `Date.get/setYear` has been deprecated for about 10 years now.

Comment: @Johan That might be so, but there might exist reasons why I can't use JodaTime, so if it's possible I need to solve it with standard Java API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Z` in your format string means that the timezone is being dynamically set from the `dateString` and the timeZone of the formatter itself is ignored for `parse()`.  Since the dateString says `PST` the date is `PST`

Add the 4-digit year to your format and `dateString`

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't make a difference if I remove the `Z` from the `sourceSDFformatter` and update my `dateString` and remove the `PST` from it in the replaceAll()-method.

Comment: Try prepending the 4-digit year to both your format and the data so you parse it rather than set it after the fact.

Comment: That did it! Although I'm not sure how I like my solution for it, but it seems to work, even if it's a bit ugly :-) `String dateString = "Mar 20th, 10:00 AM PST".replaceAll("st|nd|rd|th", "").replace("PST", "2013");` So I guess the answer is to "always" make sure you have the year in the date string when trying to parse it with SimpleDateFormat, or use `JodaTime` :-)