# Can't convert time to GMT

Tags: java, date, calendar, gmt

My problem is that I want to convert the local time to `GMT`. I am able to convert the actual time and save it to Parse but the problem is that Parse applies its own:

> Wed Feb 24 10:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016

This is the date that I am getting after converting to `GMT00:00` but the problem is the  `GMT+05:30` that is actually false as my date is actually in `GMT`. Now when I put this date in the server it further decreases the time by 5:30 hrs. So how can we change this `GMT+05:30` to `GMT+00:00`

Comment: Please show your code to see what you have got so far

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055407/conversion-of-local-time-zone-to-gmt-in-java

Comment: Exactly what are your inputs and outputs? Do you need a string representation of a date-time value in a certain format? Do you need an object of a certain type?

Answer (score 1):

We'll start with the current local time.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // automatically produces and instance of the current date/time
```

As I understand it, your local *date* is accurate to `GMT` but your *time* is 5:30 ahead of actual `GMT`.

In order to subtract 5:30 from your local time you can perform the following.

```
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -5);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -30);

System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Conversely, if you would like to *add* to the time field, you can simply use:

```
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 5); // note I have removed the minus(-) symbol
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30); // note I have removed the minus(-) symbol

System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java 8. you could utilize from the new time library.
As you tell it seems what you want, is to have a stamp in UTC which is GMT+00

more about time library [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

This line:

```
System.out.println(Instant.now().toString());
```

gives

> 2016-02-25T17:54:55.420Z

Hope it makes thing more clear to you.

Comment: No need for offset. [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is in UTC by definition. `Instant.now().toString()`